# Comparison and conditional check in Java ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have an Array List of some custom object. That custom object has a Date field.

I have a method that has List above and one Date as an arguments. Now I need to find the latest record from the list before the Date that is passed as an argument.

Can someone please let me know the best way to do it?

Comment: Could you add the code you're talking about?

Comment: Pre-sort the list. Or better yet, use a sorted queue.

Comment: Iterate through the list.  Keep track of which item in the list has the latest eligible `Date` that you've discovered so far.

Comment: Why the close votes?  This question is clear as it stands, and very much about programming.

Comment: @DavidWallace: i guess because people want to know what Anand has tried. my suggestions: sort the array by the date field before iterating over the array

Comment: @DavidWallace no efforts shown, nothing tried. I don't know how you think, but I'm not a "do homework free for bogus reps" service, and as I see, the spirit of [SO] also dictates questions that display efforts, not asking for code. No effort, no chocolate.

Comment: @ppeterka66 Fair enough. Good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep track of an eligible `Date`, and use the `getTime()` API to update the eligible variable. This code could be optimized, but I think you got the idea.

```
public static COjbect getClosestRecordToDate(final List<CObject> list, final Date date)
{
     if (list == null || list.isEmpty())
          return null;

     final CObject temp = list.get(0);

     for (final CObject obj : list)
     {
          final long time = obj.getDate().getTime();

          if (time < date.getTime() && time > temp.getTime())
               temp = obj;
     }

     return temp;
}
```

**Edit**: Thanks to @David Wallace for the edit.